# Need help deleting temp directory universally

Tags: c#, directory

I am having a problem in C# when trying to delete the directory (`C:\Users\Terry\AppData\Local\Temp`).

This is my current code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\"+ System.Environment.MachineName + "\AppData\Local\Temp");
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(dir.ToString()))
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work for me. I'm fairly new to C# and I'm not familiar with deleting directories. Anybody able to help?

Comment: This is utterly lazy. Obviously you haven't read the documentation, but you haven't even read what you have written. What do you think `File.Delete` does?

Comment: Seems like there should be a method or two in NET to get those folder names for us.

Comment: `Path.GetTempPath()` will give you that exact path you are after. Also worth looking at `Environment.GetSpecialFolderPath()` to get other special folders. But if you want to delete the directory and all its files/subfolders you should call `dir.Delete(true)`. If you're going to iterate the files it's better to use `di.EnumerateFiles()` since you already have a `DirectoryInfo`. Or at least use `di.FullName` instead of `ToString()` since there's a known issue with `ToString()` called on a `DirectoryInfo` object obtained via the `Parent` property where it only returns the name

Answer (score 2):

Using the File.Delete method tries to delete a file. You want the `Directory.Delete` method to delete a directory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, if you are creating temporary files or directory it is much better to use `Path.GetTempPath()` method. This will work in all version of Windows and respect any environment variables the user has set.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users", Environment.UserName, @"AppData\Local\Temp" );
Directory.Delete(path, true);
```